# Use string as variable name in BASH script

Tags: bash

I have the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

n=('fred' 'bob')

f='n'
echo ${${f}[@]}
```

and I need that bottom line after substitutions to execute

```
echo ${n[@]}
```

any way to do this? I just get

```
test.sh: line 8: ${${f}}: bad substitution
```

on my end.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do variable indirection with arrays like this:

```
subst="$f[@]"
echo "${!subst}"
```

As soulmerge notes, you shouldn't use `#!/bin/sh` for this. I use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as my shebang, which should work regardless of where Bash is in your path.

Comment: +1 Indirect expansion is far less of a bug magnet than `eval`.

Answer (score 6):

You could `eval` the required line:

```
eval "echo \${${f}[@]}"
```

BTW: Your first line should be `#!/bin/bash`, you're using bash-specific stuff like arrays

Comment: +1 if I had any votes remaining today. Can you explain what eval does?

Comment: I do not understand why people keep downvoting without providing any feedback?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but in general things like `eval` should be avoided in most languages if there is an alternative. They sometimes introduce subtle bugs or security risks.