# Variation on a Variable Variable in Bash

Tags: bash

I am looking for a way to add a string to a variable name in bash and evaluate this as a new variable. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="filename"
declare ${file}_info="about a file"
declare ${file}_status="status of file"
declare ${file}_number="29083451"

echo ${${file}_info}  # <-- This fails with error: "bad substitution"
```

Is there a way to do this?

**I'm not actually implementing this** in any production code anywhere. I just want to know if there is some way to create a variable name using a variable and a string. It seemed like an interesting problem.

Also note that I am **not** asking about bash indirection, which is the use of `${!x}` to evaluate the contents of a variable as a variable.

Comment: It looks like the eval approach given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435256/use-string-as-variable-name-in-bash-script might be the one you are looking for.

Comment: The indirection FAQ tells you how to write, not just how to read, so it actually _is_ the same topic.

Comment: Agreed. As I have reviewed comments and answers, it would seem that indirection must be involved in the solution. I was hoping for another way, but it seems that there is at least one solution if indirection is used in the process.

Comment: @jpe, re: eval, see BashFAQ #48: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't asking about indirection, but that's what can help you:

```
info=$file\_info
echo ${!info}
```

Comment: Apparently my edit was rejected. It seems that your answer should say `${!info}` instead of `${!name}`. I had also hoped to achieve this without using a placeholder variable like "info" that you are using here, but you have indeed solved the problem. Will accept your answer.